# How to generate a dict from an 2 dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to generate from an 2 dimensional list a dictionary.

The key of the dictionary should be the indexes of the array position (x,y). The value should be a list with all the neighbors (up, down, right, left) of this array position. The value is the position of the neighbor.

Example of a 4x4 2 dimensional list:

input:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

output:

```
graph = {
    '0,0': ["0,1", "1,0"],
    '0,1': ["0,0", "1,1", "0,2"],
    '0,2': ["0,1", "0,3", "1,2"],
    '0,3': ["0,2", "1,3"],

    '1,0': ["0,0", "1,1", "2,0"],
    '1,1': ["0,1", "1,0", "2,1", "1,2"],
    '1,2': ["0,2", "1,1", "2,2", "1,3"],
    '1,3': ["0,3", "1,2", "2,3"],

    '2,0': ["1,0", "3,0", "2,1"],
    '2,1': ["2,0", "3,1", "2,2", "1,1"],
    '2,2': ["1,2", "2,1", "3,2", "2,3"],
    '2,3': ["1,3", "2,2", "3,3"],

    '3,0': ["2,0", "3,1"],
    '3,1': ["2,1", "3,0", "3,2"],
    '3,2': ["2,2", "3,1", "3,3"],
    '3,3': ["2,3", "3,2"],
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I think there is maybe an easy solution but I can't find anyone.

Comment: ... *"So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?"* If you have **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If you have no code, then write some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this algorithm will do

```
grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]] #input

dic = dict()
for i in xrange(len(grid)):
    for j in xrange(len(grid[0])):
        x = []
        for k in [(0, 1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]:
            if 0 <= i + k[0] < len(grid) and 0 <= j + k[1] < len(grid[0]):
                x.append((i + k[0], j + k[1]))
        dic[(i, j)] = x
```

dictionary `dic` is what you want

Comment: ohh the last entry in the list is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me now. I'm open for any improvement.

```
size_y = 4
size_x = 4

l = [[0 for x in range(size_y)] for x in range(size_x)]
d = {}

for x in range(size_x):
    for y in range(size_y):
        key = "{},{}".format(x, y)
        # edges
        if x == 0 and y == 0:
            l = ["0,1", "1,0"]
        elif x == size_x-1 and y == size_y-1:
            l = ["{},{}".format(x,y-1), "{},{}".format(x-1,y)]
        elif x == size_x-1 and y == 0:
            l = ["{},{}".format(x-1,y),"{},{}".format(x,y+1)]
        elif x == 0 and y == size_y-1:
            l = ["{},{}".format(0,y-1),"{},{}".format(x+1,y)]
        else:
            l = []
            #N x y-1
            if y-1 >= 0:
                l.append("{},{}".format(x, y-1))
            #O x+1 y
            if x+1 < size_x:
                l.append("{},{}".format(x+1, y))
            #S x y+1
            if y+1 < size_y:
                l.append("{},{}".format(x, y+1))
            #W x-1 y
            if x-1 >= 0:
                l.append("{},{}".format(x-1, y))
        d[key] = l

print(d)
```